# How to update value tooltip range boostrap?

Tags: jquery, range, slider, tooltip, bootstrap-5

i'm use bootsrap 5.0.2

```
<div class="mb-3">
    Kecerahan <input type="range" class="form-control" id="kecerahan" name="kecerahan" min="1" max="255" value="100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="100" aria-describedby="Kecerahan" required>
</div>
```

And in javvascript i'm try this, but this code not work.

```
$(function() {
   var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(
   $("#kecerahan"));
       tooltip.show();
       $("#kecerahan").change(function() {
           $("#kecerahan").attr('title', $(this).val());
       });
   });
});
```

How change tooltip value after change slide value?

Comment: First, you need to get event when changing slide : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events

Comment: Please give me example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

$("#kecerahan").on('change', function() {
   let value = $(this).val();
   $(this).attr('title', value);
});
```

Comment: I have tried code this, not work

Comment: I modified this !